# How to display a specific MVC Partial View when clicking a corresponding link?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC 5 and Visual Studio 2015. I have a very simple thing I want to do...

I have a page with a controller and NO MODEL. I don't believe I need a model, I'm not accessing or capturing any data; I simply want to display different information (views) based on what a user clicks.

I have an icon bar on the top of the page (which is its own partial) and when you click on an icon, it corresponds to a specific partial view. Click another icon, the previous info disappears and the new info displays. Easy peasy right? I'm not having any luck.

I've found at least a gazillion articles explaining how to do it for ONE partial. but what if I want to conditionally display info that isn't in a list and isn't in a database, but is simply a partial view connected to a link?

Here's some of the code...

My Controller

```
public class MyController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult _about() {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult _business() {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult _finance() {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult _jobs() {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult _locations() {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult _marketing() {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult _programming() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

}

My Markup for the Index View (the main view for this page):

```html
@using System.Configuration
@{ViewBag.Title = "Index";}

@Html.Partial("_cteIconBar") <!-- This is the row of icons -->

<div class="padding-top-50" id="partial">  
    @Html.Partial("_about")  <!-- I do want to display the "about" partial when a user first lands on the page.-->
</div>

<div class="padding-top-50" id="partial" style="display: none">  <!-- this is not working... *sigh* -->
    @{Html.RenderAction("_business"); }
    @{Html.RenderAction("_programming"); }
    @{Html.RenderAction("_finance"); }
    @{Html.RenderAction("_marketing"); }
</div>
```

My Markup for the icon bar:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="text-center margin-bottom icon-container">
            <ul>
                <li class="icon-bar-cte" id="about">
                    <a role="button" href="@Url.Action("_about", "CTE")">
                        <i class="icon-aboutInfo cte-icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="icon-bar-cte" id="business">
                    <a role="button" class="cte-icon" href="@Url.Action("_business", "CTE")">
                        <i class="icon-business cte-icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="icon-bar-cte">
                    <a role="button" href="@Url.Action("_finance", "CTE")">
                        <i class="icon-finance cte-icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="icon-bar-cte">
                    <a role="button" href="@Url.Action("_marketing", "CTE")">
                        <i class="icon-marketing cte-icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="icon-bar-cte">
                    <a role="button" href="@Url.Action("_programming", "CTE")">
                        <i class="icon-programming cte-icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="icon-bar-cte">
                    <a role="button" href="@Url.Action("_jobs", "CTE")">
                        <i class="icon-jobs cte-icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="icon-bar-cte">
                    <a role="button" href="@Url.Action("_locations", "CTE")">
                        <i class="icon-location-marker cte-icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My markup for one of the partials (they're all the same with different words). I substituted a little "Hippie Ipsum" for your pleasure.

```html
<div class="container collapse in" id="about" aria-expanded="true">
    <div class="row padding-bottom-50">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12">
            <h2 class="green">Some Hippie Ipsum for You!</h2>
            <p><strong>What is Career Technical Education?</strong></p>
            <p>Equinox plant consciousness midwifery embracing and moving towards djembe craniosacral, dolphin Hafiz ecstatic dance higher cosmic force spoken word. Prayer flags fair trade what quantum theory says, healing tonic non-profit co-create impermanent hemp seed.</p>
            <br />
            <p><strong>Why is Hippie Ipsum important?</strong></p>

            <p>Closing circle himalayan sea salt multi-dimensional honoring your truth, forest birth name. Tofurkey native american ancestry diva cup human potential yoni, bioneers the buddha sunset. Animal totem deep cleansing emotional release one taste life coach compostable toilet, be the change astrological mercury retrograde holistic.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.padding-top-50{
  padding-top:50px;
  }
```

Comment: This seems like a site where you want a layout page with your common markup and then different views (not partials).  What are you trying to accomplish with the partials?

Comment: you should use jquary and ajax call for creating partial view for every selection.

Comment: @stephen.vakil -- I do have a layout page. All that is working nicely. I should clarify, this is not the "main" index page. It's another page in another folder with its own index page. Like it's the main page for this topic. You get it.

Comment: @Hadee -- yeah, I kinda figured that would be the route I need to take but I can't figure out how to implement it for my specific needs.

Comment: what do you mean " I can't figure out how"?

Comment: Still seems like they are full views you want to link to.  You can use `Areas` to segregate your site into sections with their own Layouts, etc.

Comment: I'm not that smart man, I've just only begun my journey into the backend world. I've been doing front-end for 3 years!! So I'm syntactically handicapped.

Comment: Initially I had them as full views and placed the iconbar view as a partial on each view. Which did work nicely except for a few things I didn't like. For instance, the obvious "reload" flicker. And the :hover state change doesn't persist. You know, cause it's another page.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for what you'd like to achieve is to use AJAX so you can inject the views into the container.

So let's start from the beginning:

1) You have to return PartialView() instead of regular View()

```
public ActionResult _about() {
    return PartialView();
}
```

2) Not needed, but I'd change some things in your menu markup. Note the `data-url` instead of `href`.

```
<li class="icon-bar-cte" id="business">
    <a href="#" role="button" class="cte-icon" data-url="@Url.Action("_business", "CTE")">
        <i class="icon-business cte-icon"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

3) Most important part is the following jQuery. Depending of what you need you can use `append` instead of `html` when injecting the view.

```
$(document).on('click','.cte-icon',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: 'GET'
    }).done(function(response){
       $('#partial').html(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Another option is to use `$('#partial').load(url);` in place of `$.ajax({...});`. They both do pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Dan & @Agramer. In my controller I did have it set as PartialView, but when I did that, only the partial view appeared as the whole page. There was no layout page nor the IconBar, just the partial. I changed it back to view and then it incorporated the _layout but not the icon bar. *sigh*. I tried using the jQuery and I couldn't get that to work either. So I changed the partials to pages and just put the _cteIconBar partial on each page. It's not exactly what I want but it works for now. Hopefully I can fix it soon.

Comment: It is worth noting that if you do this people won't be able to link to anything other than the default tab.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way, if you wanna go more "vanilla" .NET MVC is to use actionlinks and return partial views from your controller actions. 
Something like this:

```
public ActionResult _programming() 
{
        PartialView("~/Views/YourPartialsPath/_programming.cshtml");
}
```

And in your views put this:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Html element text", 
                     "_programming", 
                     "MyController", 
                      new { controller = "MyController" }, 
                      new { @class = "MaybeYouWantAClassOnTheHtmlElement" })
```

And if you want you could structure your site to be a single page app by initially loading a single view to be your "base structure" container. This page would then load a set of partials consisting of maybe side/top menu bars and maybe a "main page" container. 
This main page could also be in charge of loading of some javascripts you want to run across all of your later loaded partials (maybe a function showing/hiding  an ajax.gif image)

Lets say you put this in your initial page load. 
Maybe you put this in your: \Views\Home\index.cshtml 
Or even your:               \Views_Layout.cshtml

```
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                @{ Html.RenderAction("TopMenuRenderer", "Menu");}
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                @{ Html.RenderAction("UserMenuRenderer", "Menu");}
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Then you create a controller called Menu

```
namespace WebPortal.Web.Controllers
{
    public class MenuController : Controller
    {
        [ChildActionOnly] //for ajax call to controller remove this annotation
        public ActionResult TopMenuRenderer()
        {
            //return PartialView();
            if (User.IsInRole(Role.Admin.ToString()) ||
                User.IsInRole(Role.SuperAdmin.ToString()))
            {
                return PartialView("~/Views/Menu/_TopMenu.cshtml");
            }
            return null;
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult UserMenuRenderer()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return PartialView("~/Views/Menu/_UserMenuAuthenticated.cshtml");
            else
                return PartialView("~/Views/Menu/_UserMenuNotAuthenticated.cshtml");
        }
        [ChildActionOnly] 
        public ActionResult SideMenuRenderer()
        {
            //you could put some user checks here if you want to limit some of the loaded meny options depending on the user type.
            if (User.IsInRole(Role.Admin.ToString()) ||
                User.IsInRole(Role.SuperAdmin.ToString()))
            {
                return PartialView("~/Views/Menu/_SideMenu.cshtml");
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I do have a layout page and it's working great . What I'm trying to do is something similar with the iconbar partial. I want the icon bar to be a constant for these 8 other views. So I'd have my main layout with the navigation and footer. Then I'd have the iconBar on an "index" page (under the 'about' section) and call the partials (_business; _programming; etc) and only the middle of the page changes the content depending on which icon the user clicks.